# Update Parent Case record with the new case record id created using process builder

Tags: case-object, process, builder

Requirement:- In Case record, if a user selects particular value in picklist and clicks on Save>> Create a New Case record. The new case record should be visible to user in the Related List section of the parent case.

My progress till now- I can create a new Case when conditions are met(using a Process Builder), but not able to associate in the related list of the existing case.

can anyone let me know how to associate the newly created case record with parent case using process builder?

Comment: Set the ParentId field to the existing case record Id? Should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: can you provide more details on how to do that...any process flow or graphical representation will work good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom lookup field to Case on the Case object. Then when the correct criteria is met set that lookup field's value to the parent you want to link.

[image: PB Case]

[Try this trailhead if you need more exposure to using Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder)

Comment: i have created a custom lookup on parent case. this is what you are suggesting?can you provide more details on how to do that...any process flow or graphical representation will work good.

Comment: any screenshot of process builder ? where exactly i have to add the condition? do i have to create 2 process builder, as i will get recordid of new case once it is created that means the 1st process buider is executed successfully.

Comment: Updated to include screen shot. You only need one process builder. Create the new case record when certain criteria is met on the Parent Case.

Comment: thanks a lot brother....it worked...

Comment: No problem my dude!